# Variable image does not work in a grid-container

Tags: image

I have a variable image for a grid container website. My problem is:

- It works with a static image
- It works variable if the command is executed before the grid container (then of course the image does not come in the right position)
- It does not work if the command is executed inside the grid container.

Here is a part of the code:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu main main main right right'
    'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 3% 95% 2%;    
   gap: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}   
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }     
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$Zufallszahl = mt_rand() %69+1;
$Hintergrundbild = "Cook_" . $Zufallszahl . ".jpg";
$Hintergrundbild = "https://retslop-subdom5a.synology.me/wp-content/uploads/Fotos/Kochbuch/" . $Hintergrundbild;
?>
<?php/*
require "ImagePicker.php";   */              **//Instead of the above code**
?>
<!--<div><img src=//<?php echo $Hintergrundbild ?> alt="LA" style="height:600px"></div>                                                                             **This code functions: the image is shown - but on the wrong place-->**
<?php 
$Tabelle = $_GET['subject'];
?>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1"><h1>Schäff ist Chef!!</h1></div>
        <div class="item2"><ul>
           <li><a href="Bedienungsanleitung.html">Hilfe</a></li>
           <li><a href="Cookbook_win_1.html">NeuStart</a></li></ul>  
           <h5>Top-News</h5>
           <h2><b>Hast Du eine fette Suppe und ein gutes Weib,dann sei zufrieden....oder...!</b></h2>
           <h5><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></h5>
           <h4>© 2024 Daniel Blumendraht</h4></div>
        <div class="item3"><img src=<?php echo $Hintergrundbild ?> alt="" style="height:600px"></div>   **<!--This does not work: no picture inserted, but the rest of the text before the >character-->**
        <div class="item4"><h5>Wer Hilfe braucht klickt links oben auf "Hilfe", sonst geht's weiter mit Klick auf die "Goodies". Kontaktmöglichkeit findet man links unten...</h5></div>
        <div class="item5"><h3>Never trust a skinny cook</h3></p></div>
 
    </div>
```

I tried to put the image defining code into the grid container. I tried to expand the PHP end character at the end of the grid container. I tried to put the image search before the grid container (it works, but not in the right area) The usage of a constant image works in the grid container of course.